# Cannot get the values in time period using SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let me explain the process:

1. We've got a scanned questionnaries.
2. The OCR system processes these questionnaries to get data.
3. Then all recognized data(form_id, question_number, answer etc) goes into database.
4. For each form there are about 120-150 rows in database:

   - `53453, 1, A, 2016-10-30 23:54:18.590`
   - `53453, 2, B, 2016-10-30 23:54:18.690`
   - `53453, 3, C, 2016-10-30 23:54:18.790` so on

As you can see, it is difficult enough to find duplicate of a questionnarie form in the database. SQL is not my strong point so I need your help) I need to select ID according to the condition: insertionTime difference of 1 min is not a duplicate. But if the ID exists somwhere else in another Time it would be a dublicate.
P.S. I did my best trying to explain my issue. Excuse me for my english)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your last column's data type is DATETIME the do:

```
SELECT tA.*
FROM MyTable tA INNER JOIN MyTable tB ON (tA.ID = tB.ID AND tA.question_number = tB.question_number AND tA.answer = tB.answer)
WHERE DATEDIFF(minute,tA.DateColumn,tB.DateColumn) < 2 -- DATEDIFF returns INT
```

Answer (score 0):

You check only ID or also question and answer? I wrote my query for only ID and Date because You said If ID exists in other row with different time ( difference is more than minute - it is duplicate)  you don't say anything about checking answer / question. In last row I modified time.

```
DECLARE @TMP TABLE (
    ID INT,
    VALUE INT,
    VALUE2 VARCHAR(5),
    DATES DATETIME
)

INSERT INTO @TMP
SELECT 53453, 1, 'A', '2016-10-30 23:54:18.590'

INSERT INTO @TMP
SELECT 53453, 2, 'B', '2016-10-30 23:54:18.690'

INSERT INTO @TMP
SELECT 53453, 3, 'C', '2016-10-30 23:56:20.590'


SELECT ID, MIN(DATES) DATES
INTO #TMP_ID
FROM @TMP
GROUP BY ID

-- MORE THAN MINUTE
SELECT *
FROM @TMP T
WHERE EXISTS (

    SELECT NULL
    FROM #TMP_ID X
    WHERE DATEDIFF(second, x.dates, t.DATES) > 60
    and x.id = t.id

)

-- LESS THAN MINUTE
SELECT *
FROM @TMP T
WHERE NOT EXISTS (

    SELECT NULL
    FROM #TMP_ID X
    WHERE DATEDIFF(second, x.dates, t.DATES) > 60
    and x.id = t.id

)


DROP TABLE #TMP_ID
```